# multiple dropdown values not able set component state

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have tried multiple dropdown in ractjs applicaton i need to set state this values but not setting values.Then trying to get values on form submit but statemembers got undefined.Can some one help me out this problem

```
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class GroupCreation extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            members: [],
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log('handle submit event:', event);
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('state values:', this.state);
    }
    render() {
        const { t } = this.props;

        if (this.props.DriverInfolistReducer.driverInfolist.length > 0) {
            this.driverUId = this.props.DriverInfolistReducer.driverInfolist.map((drivers, index) => {
                console.log('driver in group list:', drivers);
                return {
                    key: index,
                    text: drivers.userid,
                    value: drivers.userid
                };
            });
        }
        return (

            <AUX>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form-horizontal m-t-30">
                    <div className="form-group row">
                        <label htmlFor="members-input" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Members</label>
                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                            <Dropdown fluid multiple selection options={this.driverUId} onChange={(e, data) => this.setState({ members: data.values })} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group row justify-content-end" >
                        <div className="button-items d-flex  p-l-10">
                            <Button size="sm" outline color="primary" onClick={this.clearInput} type="button">{t('Cancel')}</Button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="button-items d-flex p-l-10">
                            <Button size="sm" outline color="primary" type="submit" >{t('Save')}</Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </AUX>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to add the code for your whole component I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of callback function `onChange` holds data.

try this:

```
<Dropdown fluid multiple selection options={this.driverUId} value={this.state.members} onChange={(e,data) => this.setState({ members: data.value })} />
```

[live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-ub7p3)

Comment: It should be. Have u ever console the `data`?

Comment: yes data has 
value: Array(3)
0: "DRI36"
1: "DRI41"
2: "DRI45"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: but not updating to state

Comment: I expected it to be a simple value, however it's an array. Is that intended?

Comment: @SaranViji Not a problem. If it solved your question, could you mark it solved? Thx.